# how to create a readable stream from a remote URL and pass it into another API without saving it into the local file system in nodejs using got?

Tags: node.js, stream, node.js-got

I want to access an image from a remote URL and pass it into another API request as request body.
I am using [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) [stream API](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/3-streams.md) library to stream the data from the external url.

```
const url = "https://media0.giphy.com/media/4SS0kfzRqfBf2/giphy.gif";

got.stream(url).pipe(createWriteStream('image.gif'));

const response= await axsios.post('post_url',fs.createReadStream('image.gif');
```

The download operation is working as expected, but I don't want write the data to the local system.Instead, I woud like pass the response from the [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) [stream API](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/3-streams.md)  to another API as a request body.